# how to batch combine two sequence of images with an alpha channel using ffmpeg or imagemagick?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, imagemagick, png, alpha

Other tools or Simple APIs are also welcome.

I have a sequence of pngs with alpha that I want to overlay on top of a few videos.
Using ffmpeg would be fantastic, but using imagemagick is also acceptable. I could extract all the frames in the video and use imagemagick to batch blend every frame then re-encode (re-encoding is acceptable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ffmpeg` example. You mentioned "two sequences" so this example assumes you have two sets of sequentially numbered images:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -framerate 25 -i blue_%04d.png -framerate 25 -i red_%04d.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=10:10:format=auto[bg];[bg][2]overlay=W-w-10:10:format=auto[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -c:a copy output.mp4
```

[image]
<sub>Example of overlay placements.</sub>

- The first image sequence ("`blue`") will be placed in the top left with 10px padding and the second ("`red`") in the top right. If you want bottom left: `10:H-h-10`. If you want bottom right: `W-w-10:H-h-10`.
- The images in this example are named `blue_0001.png`, `blue_0002.png`, `blue_0003.png`, etc. The pattern is the same for the "`red`" sequence.
- See the [image file demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) and [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify about the sequence of pngs. Do you want all pngs overlaying each frame of the video. Or one different png per every frame of the video. Or the same one png (selectable) overlaying each frame of the video.

The latter can be done in ImageMagick using -layers composite, assuming  your ImageMagick has ffmpeg as a delegate library

```
convert video.mpeg null: overlay.png -gravity G -geometry +X+Y -layers composite new_video.mpeg
```

I am not sure, but you may need to add -coalesce after the video.mpeg, if the frames are optimized in some way to change the frame sizes as in gif animations.

Alternately, suppose you convert all video frames to png. Then assuming all frames are the same size and numbered with leading zeros,

```
convert video*.png null: overlay.png -gravity G -geometry +X+Y -layers composite new_video.mpeg
```

where G is the gravity setting such as center, X and Y are the desired offsets from the gravity setting.

or

```
convert video*.png null: overlay.png -gravity G -geometry +X+Y -layers composite new_video_%03d.png
```

where you can change %03d.png to have any number other than 3 to set the number of leading zeros. Then you will have to use ffmpeg to reconstitute your video.